# (Windows 8 store app) Refresh current page if 5 minutes passed from entering suspended state till next running state

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8, winrt-xaml

As mentioned in the title, I want the current page's content to refresh when turning from suspended state to running state, but only if 5 minutes passed from when I entered the suspended state.
How can I count time while the app is suspended and probably regular timer won't continue to run when the app is suspended?

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the system time somewhere in the local data folder when you get suspended, then read and compare that saved time with the system time when you next run.

For 5 minutes, that's as good a resolution as you need.

Comment: I think you could also store it in memory as well. Either way.

Comment: You could, but storing it on disk means it will work as well if the app is terminated rather than suspended.